# "vue","v-for","item is not defined",why?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

here is my html,when I use 'v-for',the wrong is 'item is not defined'.

```
    <form action="">
        <div class=" form-group">
            <tr>
                <th v-for="item in title">{{item}} </th>
            </tr>
      </div>
    </form>
```

```
new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            
            title:['name','sort','company'],
        }
)
```

I don't know how to do with the problems.please help me ,thank you very much

Comment: Where in your HTML is your `#app` element ?

Comment: I have no idea why, but once I've changed `div.form-group` in `table.form-group` (because `tr` can only be used in a `table`) it worked. no more error message

Comment: I added the <table>,and then it works,thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`data` should be a function which returns an object.

```
data() {
  return {
    title: ['name','sort','company']
  }
}
```